# Using Dominator Tree in igraph package R

Tags: r, tree, igraph, minimum-spanning-tree

Ultimately I need a df that holds every vertex and its parent (with wither NA or NULL for the root) so if anyone has a way to get that using a different method it would be equally appreciated.

For now I have the following using igraph and their built in functions with code as follows:

```
g <- graph.adjacency(-weight_matrix, weighted = T)
g <- minimum.spanning.tree(g)
```

Now the graph is a minimum spanning *GRAPH*.  It is not directed and doesn't have a single root node.  After a lot of searching I found the `dominator.tree` function and have tried to run the following code with errors as follows

```
> dominator.tree(g, 1)
Error in simple_vs_index(V(graph), idx, na_ok = na_ok) : 
  Unknown vertex selected
> dominator.tree(g, 2)
Error in simple_vs_index(V(graph), idx, na_ok = na_ok) : 
  Unknown vertex selected
> dominator.tree(g, V(g)[1])
Error in simple_vs_index(V(graph), idx, na_ok = na_ok) : 
  Unknown vertex selected
> dominator.tree(g, V(g))
Error in simple_vs_index(V(graph), idx, na_ok = na_ok) : 
  Unknown vertex selected
```

In the documentation it asks for the vertex ID, but I have not been able to figure out how to provide that.

Edit:

```
dominator.tree(g, root = 1)
dominator.tree(g, root = 2)
```

both returned the same error `unknown vertex selected` with the same error message as above

Comment: Workaround: `igraph_options(return.vs.es = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, the root vertex of the graph has to be specified using a named argument - a simple positional argument is not enough. So, this will not work:

```
> dominator.tree(g, 2)
```

but this will:

```
> dominator.tree(g, root=2)
```

Comment: I get an error that states that `Error in simple_vs_index(V(graph), idx, na_ok = na_ok) : 
  Unknown vertex selected
Called from: simple_vs_index(V(graph), idx, na_ok = na_ok)`

Comment: I updated the question.  The command was `dominator.tree(g,root = 1)`
If what I'm missing is the need to use a named vertex, would I be able to name the vertices of my graph? And how would I do that?  Each vertice does represent something specific and I have a character vector with the names.